# How to change text boxs specific text colour?

Tags: c#

I want to change text color of Not working Links if link is not working its color should be red. and my links are in textbox

```
if (!IsLinkWorking(link))
{
     //Here you can show the error. You don't specify how you want to show 
     TextBox2.Text += string.Format(
         "{0}\nNot working\n\n ", link); 
     // this should be in red which is in textbox2.text
}
else
{
    TextBox2.Text += string.Format("{0}\n working\n\n", link);
}
```

Comment: use $(your_item).css("color", "red");

Comment: I retagged this to remove the [tag:javascript] tag, it seems not to relate to Javascript at all, but it's unclear from the question. It's C#, but are you asking about ASP.NET, or a desktop client?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the text color of the `TextBox` with the `ForeColor` property, but you can not display portions of text in a different color. You will need a `RichTextBox`, or something similar, for that.

To change the text color of a `TextBox` control:

```
TextBox2.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
TextBox2.Text += string.Format("{0}\nNot working\n\n ", link);
```

Comment: its showing error Name 'Color' does not exist in the current context

Comment: it should like this                                       `TextBox2.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                    TextBox2.Text+= string.Format("{0}\nNot working\n\n ", link);`

Comment: Yes that should work. But remember you cannot change a part of the text' color; it's all the text or nothing.

Comment: thanks but it working for all the texts links i want to apply this for not working links

Comment: i just want red color in not working links only `TextBox2.Text += string.Format( "{0}\nNot working\n\n ", link);`

Comment: Like I said in my answer, you cannot do that with a regular `TextBox` control. You will have to use a `RichTextBox` control or equivalent for that.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to take a look into the `ForeColor` property:

```
TextBox2.ForeColor = Color.Red;
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.forecolor.aspx

Comment: i just wan red color in not working links only TextBox2.Text += string.Format(
         "{0}\nNot working\n\n ", link);

Answer (score 1):

Set the ForeColor property of the textbox:

```
TextBox2.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
TextBox2.ForeColor = Color.Red;
```

or use for richTextBox1

```
this.TextBox2.SelectionColor = Color.Red;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change Font color with [ForeColor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez1ywchy%28v=VS.71%29.aspx)

*Gets or sets the foreground color of the control.*

```
TextBox2.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
```